# Single quotes do not seem to be scaled with xelatex and Source Code Pro

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, typewriter

I don't know which LaTeX packages I recently updated caused this issue, but I suddenly noticed today that my single quotes in `\texttt{}` and `verbatim` environments were not scaled correctly. I'm using xelatex with `\setmonofont[Scale=0.7]{Source Code Pro}`. Here is what single quotes look like before (in `\texttt{}`):

[image: old]

And here is what they look like now:

[image: new]

They are not scaled correctly in verbatim environments, either:

[image: same]

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.7]{Source Code Pro}

\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\texttt{'hello world'}

\texttt{\textquotesingle{}hello world\textquotesingle{}}

\begin{verbatim}
x = 'hello world'
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Output (with `xelatex` and the latest versions of all packages `tlmgr update --self --all`, and Source Code Pro downloaded from [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Code+Pro)):

[image]

So literal single quotes are scaled correctly in `\texttt{}` (first line), but `\textquotesingle{}` and single quotes in `verbatim` are problematic.

If I don't use the `upquote` package, the issue with single quotes in `verbatim` will be fixed (but I hope I can keep `upquote`):

[image]

Now I have run out of ideas, and I don't know if this issue was caused by a certain recent update of a certain package, or changes in the Source Code Pro font on Google fonts. I hope `\textquotesingle{}` and single quotes in `verbatim` can be displayed correctly (if possible, with the `upquote` package).

Comment: From the description of `upquote` on CTAN: >The pack­age switches the type­writer font to Com­puter Modern Typewriter in OT1 en­cod­ing, and mod­i­fies the be­haviour of ver­ba­tim, ver­ba­tim*, \verb, and \verb* to print in the “` and ' way”.< Your problem is that for any non-cm-font `textcomp` (an obsolete package) is loaded which also does not match your font.

Comment: They're not just a different size but a different glyph (look at the tops).  This isn't surprising given the package clash others have reported

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the new TU-encoding now used by fontspec is missing suitable definitions for `\textquotesingle` and `\textasciigrave` (which were previously present in `xunicode`) and so the default definitions from `textcomp` kicks in. If I add definitions everything is fine.

### Edit

The missing definitions have been added to the LaTeX-code. So after the next update of LaTeX is should work correctly out-of-the-box.

### Edit 2

The code in my example works fine as only typewriter fonts are used. With a roman font it is more complicated as the "TeX-ligatures" interferes. Some discussion is going on.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.7]{Source Code Pro}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textquotesingle}     \UnicodeEncodingName{"0027}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textasciigrave}     \UnicodeEncodingName{"0060}


\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\texttt{'hello world'}

\texttt{\textquotesingle{}hello world\textquotesingle{}}

\begin{verbatim}
x = 'hello world'
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I found the tilde also need to be fixed: `\DeclareTextSymbol{\textasciitilde}     \UnicodeEncodingName{"007E}`. BTW, carets become problematic as well but it seems to be a different issue, so I posted a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354258/9128

Comment: I updated the latex package today, and unfortunately it is broken now no matter if I add the definitions you mentioned or not. The log file: http://pastebin.com/yLZfzCEq

Comment: there is a bug in tuenc. Try if this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355239/2388

Comment: No, same error after I tried the solution there.

Comment: Your latex is not up-to-date. `LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>`. See also the `fontspec warning: "tu-clash"` in your log. If you really updated latex then you didn't regenerate the formats correctly. (I have LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 2).

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can do besides `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` to update latex. I'm using MacTeX. I have tried `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall latex` but it still shows the date 2016/03/31.

Comment: Did you try fmtutil-sys?

Comment: Okay, `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks! I actually tried `sudo fmtutil-sys` before you replied but didn't succeed, so I gave up without looking at the help page. I'm afraid an average user is very unlikely to figure this out...

Answer (score 3):

From the description of `upquote` on CTAN:

> The pack­age switches the type­writer font to Com­puter Modern
>   Typewriter in OT1 en­cod­ing, and mod­i­fies the be­haviour of
>   ver­ba­tim, ver­ba­tim*, \verb, and \verb* to print in the “` and '
>   way”.

Your problem is that for any non-cm-font `textcomp` (an obsolete package) is loaded which also does not match your font. So you cannot use `textcomp` and because it depends on it, you cannot use `upquote` either.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea which package should I use if I need `\textquotesingle`? Or I just `\renewcommand` it to a single quote? It is not that I want to use it, but the background of my question is that I was converting Markdown to LaTeX through Pandoc, which converts single quotes to `\textquotesingle{}`.

Comment: @Yihui - The solution should be: (a) don't load the `upquote` and `textcomp` packages and (b) issue the instruction `\providecommand\textquotesingle{'}` to keep Pandoc happy.

Comment: @Mico Perfect. Problem solved by `\renewcommand{\textquotesingle}{'}`. I cannot use `\providecommand` since there is not a way to disable the use of `upquote` in Pandoc's template: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex Thanks a lot! I'm still puzzled why it was not a problem before (the last time I compiled my document was about a month ago, and I didn't see any changes in `upquote` recently).

Comment: @Yihui - There have recently been some updates to the `fontspec` package. I can only speculate that one of the changes was about the ways OT1-encoded glyphs are handled.

Comment: The description on CTAN is wrong, `upquote` doesn't change the typewriter font, see the documentation and the code. `textcomp` is not "obsolete". While it normally shouldn't be needed when using fontspec it doesn't do harm to load it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know, I wrote it under the quotation.

Comment: No you didn't. Your analysis of the source of the problem and your conclusion ("you cannot use upquote") are both wrong.