# Carets \^{} not rendered correctly

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, typewriter

After fixing the issue [Single quotes do not seem to be scaled with xelatex and Source Code Pro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354136/9128), I discovered that carets also failed to render with my recent LaTeX update. This is what they looked like in PDF before (about a month ago):

[image: old]

Now they look like this:

[image: new]

A minimal example (to be compiled via `xelatex`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

two carets (\texttt{\^{}}) produce a superscript (e.g.,
\texttt{ClO\^{}-1\^{}} renders ClO\textsuperscript{-1})

\end{document}
```

I know I probably should use `\textasciicircum{}` instead of `\^{}`, but this is not under my control, since I'm using Pandoc to convert my Markdown source document to LaTeX, and `^` is translated to `\^{}`. FWIW, this works correctly but I wonder if I can make `\^{}` work:

```
two carets (\texttt{\textasciicircum{}}) produce a superscript (e.g.,
\texttt{ClO\textasciicircum{}-1\textasciicircum{}} renders ClO\textsuperscript{-1})
```

Comment: Imho you should ask pandoc to change its output. Even if you can use a lot of tricks to tweak the output on the latex side it is not a sane input to use an accent command to get a char. `\textasciicircum` or `\string^`  would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test if `#1` is empty

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\let\OldCircum\^
\def\^#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax
    \textasciicircum
  \else
    \OldCircum#1%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}

two carets (\texttt{\^{}}) produce a superscript (e.g.,
\texttt{ClO\^{}-1\^{}} renders ClO\textsuperscript{-1})

\^o
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes I wonder if we should do that in the core...

Comment: and the same for `\textasciitilde`

Comment: yes the default TU accents use suffix combining characters and the helper function for that should probably guard against empty base in all cases.

Comment: After I updated the latex package today, this solution is broken. The log file: http://pastebin.com/yLZfzCEq My original example also fails to compile now.

Comment: Sorry please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355239/1090

Answer (score 2):

The issue applies to all accents in TU encoding. If no precomposed glyph is present then it falls back to using a combining character but if the base is empty this then combines with the previous character.

we should fix this in the base release but you can add a guard so that an empty base is detected and replaced by no-break space.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\def\add@unicode@accent#1#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\string^^a0\else#2\fi\char#1\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

two carets (\texttt{\^{}}) produce a superscript (e.g.,
\texttt{ClO\^{}-1\^{}} renders ClO\textsuperscript{-1})

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for my original example, but does not work if I use a custom font, e.g. add `\setmonofont[Scale=0.7]{Source Code Pro}` to the preamble. Output: http://i.imgur.com/Z9WDMNn.png

Comment: @Yihui that's what makes unicode setting "interesting" unlike traditional tex where we had complete control, with opentype it's more like making a general request that the font does something, but ultimately it can do whatever it likes.    Thanks for the example, I'll need to think about what to do in the default format settings

Comment: @Yihui there is something very odd about the combining `^` in that font, see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35520593#35520593

Comment: Like Herbert's answer above, this solution is also broken after a latex update today. Log file at http://pastebin.com/yLZfzCEq It seems `\DeclareTextComposite{\^}             \UnicodeEncodingName {}{"005E}` on line 252 of tuenc.def is problematic.

Comment: @Yihui yes sorry _all_ accent commands in tu encoding are broken, please apply the change shown here, I'll get an update to ctan today http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355239/1090

Comment: @Yihui the line you point to is Ok that's what makes your example of Source Code Pro work, but the if test that I added, which should have been the code in this answer got corrupted and only had \else and not `\if`, please see the fix in the link above

Comment: After I apply the fix you mentioned, and ran `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`, I was able to compile the document. Thanks!

Comment: @Yihui the fixed code is on ctan so will probably get to texlive tomorrow or the day after, sorry about the inconvenience.